# Find wait reason in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm running a Java application with an Oracle 10g. I've discovered kind of a race condition that leads to an inifite long waiting time for an UPDATE statement.

To solve this situation I'd like to find out what this statement is waiting for (locks on certain tables caused by statement xy etc.).

I tried to use the Oracle Enterprise Manager which has found this situation as well but it doesn't tell my the reason for the wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the lock tables, or if you are using a tool such as Toad, you can use the session browser to find possible locks.

Here's a [link](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dynamic_performance_views.html) to oracle system tables

Comment: The lock tables show the waiting sessions and I could find out that there is a transaction that blocks. But that doesn't really help me because there's no more information about the transaction.
This page has helped me: http://www.orafaq.com/node/854

I'll probably find a way around the problem.